# How to sort table with columns not from database

Tags: 7

I have table with both fields from database and field that is calculated using values from database. Now I can only sort table by using columns form database. Can I do it also on this other field?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369624/mysql-sort-on-a-calculation - Something like this ?